# Counting Occurences Given Values of Other Column R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a probably quite easy question to answer, but haven't been able to find a good solution to it.

I have a data frame with two columns, sales and contact, both filled with either 0 or 1.

```
sale    <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
contact <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)

df <- data.frame(sale = sale, contact = contact)
```

I want to create two events, a before and an after event. An after event is the length between two successive contacts (including the first contact itself). In this case, we will have

```
after = c(4,4,4)
```

A before event is the length of two previous contacts. In this case, we will have

```
before = c(3,4,4,4)
```

where I have included the three previous weeks of the first contact.

Next, I want to count the occurrences of a sale in the individual periods, for both after and before. So, I want to count how many sales there were between two successive contacts (after periods) or two previous contacts (before periods).

At the moment, I am doing it with diff() to calculate the difference between the indices where there is a contact and then counting how many sales there were between the indices. Something like:

```
df$sale    <- revalue(df$sale, c("0" = "np", "1" = "p"))
df$contact <- revalue(df$contact, c("0" = "n", "1" = "y"))

ik <- which(df$contact == "y") -1  ## this tell us the number of weeks
                                   ## before the event

before <- append(ik[1], diff(ik))

ct.before <- vector(mode="numeric", length = length(before))
for (i in 1:(length(before)-1)) {
   p <- df$sale[before[i]:before[i+1]]
   i1 <- which(p == "p")
   ct.before[i] <- length(i1)
}
```

And similar for after.

Of course, the above data frame is a simple and easy data frame. It can be much larger and with contacts occurrences more or less separated between them.

If there a simpler, faster way to do this?

Comment: the question is unclear. How do you define the 3 in the length of two previous contact? You moreover do not do it per contact ... otherwise the vector would have been longer.

Comment: I'm kind of got lost in that whole wording. Can you please add your exact dsired output?

Comment: an effort on the wording would reflect clear understanding on the problem ... and maybe an own solve ...